# matched records between sheets, if found search for series of strings, report binomial code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that will select records in sheet1, column A (1 row per record) and attempt to match to records in sheet2, column A (zero to 40 rows per record).
If a match is found, I want the macro to search from a list of strings (found in sheet3, A1:A75) that may appear in the sheet2 matched rows, column F.  If the records match, and one
of the target strings is found, I want the macro to enter "1" for the row being matched in sheet1, column P, 0 if no match is found. And then continue looping through all of the records of sheet1, column A. I haven't included my working code because it would be laughable to you all. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Good description of what you are trying to accomplish.  Please feel free to include your code.  Don't be embarrassed, the only shame would be to miss the opportunity to help you or learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked a question without providing any code, I'm giving you an answer which is probably going to have to be adapted to what you are trying to do.

My macro looks for value from sheet1 and in sheet2 and returns matched values.

```
Sub MatchRecord()
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

i = 1
Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1) = "" 'do until empty cell in A column (in first sheet)
    CompareValue = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1)
    j = 1
    Do Until Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1) = "" ' do until empty cell in A column (in second sheet)

            If CompareValue = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1) Then
            FindedValue = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 2)      'if CompareValue is funded in sheet2 it will return value in next column of matching row
            Else
            End If
    Loop
    Sheets("Arkusz2").Cells(i, 2) = FindedValue ' Cell in next column of searching cell will takes value from funded value
    FindedValue = "" ' clear this variable
    i = i + 1 'next cell to compare
    Loop

End Sub
```